# How to manage a thread using an event loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, timer

I created a class `MyThread` to process incoming data from the network using a separate thread. Basically, I created a multi-client server, as it receives the data, adds them to a shared queue. The thread `MyThread` gets the data from the shared queue until it is present at least one element in this queue.

```
void MyThread::run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        _mutex.lock();
        if (_stopping)
        {
            _stopping = false;
            _mutex.unlock();
            break;
        }
        _mutex.unlock();

        QString data;
        if (_queue.dequeue(data))
        {
            process(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I should use a timer within this thread, because I need to periodically change some data within the class `MyThread`. In this regard, I have read the documentation available on [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/timers.html), but I should use an event loop within the thread `MyThread`. How to change the class `MyThread` to manage the thread with an event loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get an event loop in `QThread` is to *not* subclass it. The default implementation of `QThread::run()` calls `QThread::exec()` which starts an event loop.

This means the code which is currently in your `run()` override would have to go into a separate worker class, meaning you separate the actual work from the thread control, which also makes your code a lot more flexible.

There is an example in the [QThread Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/latest/qthread.html#details); I highly recommend the first example which does not subclass `QThread`.